# Do groups of prime order have one subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, normal-subgroups

So let's say that I have a group of order $p$, where p is prime; does that group only have one subgroup?

I've look at the wiki article and it says there's a trivial and actual solution, so can we somewhat say it is only one group that exists.

I apologize if I am misinterpreting this.

Thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** By [Langrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) if $H < G$ then $|H|$ divides $p$. As $p$ is prime then we must have $|H| = 1$ or $|H| = p$.

What can you conclude from that?

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks. So isn't that just saying the size of the subgroups can be of length 1 (which i'm assuming is the trivial group) and a subgroup of length p (which is the prime number) which is the group we care about. By length I mean the number of elements in the group.

Comment: Yes, from this you know exactly what are the subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

A group of order $p$ has $2$ subgroups: the trivial subgroup and the entire group.